# How to set an attirbutes list when creating new object

Tags: python, list, class, oop, object

Hope the title was not too confusing. I've been working on program and I have created so attribut with a default list in it. The thing is I don't know how to do modification to that list when I create this object. Thank you

````py
    def __init__(self,nm,pm,adss):
        self._nom =  nm
        self._prenom = pm
        self._adresse = adss
        self._bonus = [0,0,0,0]```

employer1 = Employe("nom","prenom","adresse",[0,250,50,10] #For exemple I wanted to set 
#the list for that one. But im not sure if I can do it like that or if I might need to create a new function for it.
````

Comment: Can you always pass `bonus` as a parameter? If so then you can treat it like all other parameters.

Comment: If you want to have a default on `[0,0,0,0]`, that you can override in some cases, you can do that too but there is a common gotcha with it - see https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: just predefined `bonus` as `def __init__(self,nm,pm,adss, bonus=[0,0,0,0]):` and change `self._bonus = [0,0,0,0]` to `self._bonus = bonus`

Comment: @sahasrara62: Bad idea. That's a mutable default argument bug.

Comment: as @user2357112supportsMonica said add `None` in parameter defination and if want to keep default value to [0,0,0,0] then use if statement`,  just predefined `bonus` as `def __init__(self,nm,pm,adss, bonus=None):` and change `self._bonus = [0,0,0,0]` to `self._bonus = bonus if bonus else [0,0,0,0]`

Answer (score 0):

The current version would not work, since you are not passing that list as a parameter to the initialisation function. Your `__init__` function would need to look like this:

```
def __init__(self,nm,pm,adss,bns):
    self._nom =  nm
    self._prenom = pm
    self._adresse = adss
    self._bonus = bns
```

Then the initialiser knows that it should expect a fourth parameter to apply to the `_bonus` attribute.

Note that this will only set the attribute when *creating* the object. To *change* it once the object is created, you should create a setter function.

I'm not certain from your question if you want a default set for the bonus as standard. If so, see the comments on your question for details on how to do that.

Comment: I just wanted to if I could set new value for the object list when I add it to that class. But it's seems that I will need to create a set instead. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You could give an *immutable* default value to the `bonus` argument, then assign to `self._bonus` depending on whether or not a value was passed.

It is usually good practice to make a copy of the mutable parameters passed as argument to an object.

```
def __init__(self, nom, prenom, adresse, bonus=None):
    self._nom =  nom
    self._prenom = prenom
    self._adresse = adresse
    self._bonus = [] if bonus is None else bonus[:]  # make a copy of the mutable parameter
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def __init__(self, nom, prenom, adresse, bonus=None):
    self._nom =  nom
    self._prenom = prenom
    self._adresse = adresse
    self._bonus = bonus if bonus else [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Reasons that this answers the question:**

- You don't want to make a list literal (one of these: `[]`) be the default parameter to a function/method call. This is the *immutable* default value bug everyone's talking about.
- Setting the `bonus` parameter's default to `None` and then performing a check to see if a different value was passed is the way to go.
- The cleanest way to make a check on the value of the `bonus` parameter is shown above.